# highlight sub-match in vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying to figure out how to highlight a specific portion of a match in vim.

Given the following example rule (taken from the coffeescript syntax file [source](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script/blob/master/syntax/coffee.vim#L47)):

```
syn match coffeeExtendedOp /\%(\S\s*\)\@<=[+\-*/%&|\^=!<>?.]\+\|[-=]>\|--\|++\|:/ display
```

This regular expression matches various coffeescript operators. The operators are highlighted (in my `vimrc`) like this:

```
hi Operator guifg=#ff0000
```

For example, since coffeeExtendedOp is linked to coffeeOperator which is linked to Operator, in the above source file. This all works, but I'm wondering how to specifically highlight the `++` operator matched in the above `syn match` with a different color, say blue, within my `vimrc` (that is, without altering the original source file above). I'm simply wondering if this is possible.

**EDIT**: I think the rules are placed [under a cluster](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script/blob/master/syntax/coffee.vim#L201), so perhaps that's why it's not affecting anything. Is there a way to access the rule within the cluster?

**EDIT**: Question was clarified.

Solution:

```
syn match plusplus /++/ contained containedin=coffeeExtendedOp display
hi plusplus guifg=#0000ff
```

The problem now is that this only works when I run them as commands in vim, but not when I put it in my `vimrc` file. Any ideas? Could it be that the stuff is hidden behind the cluster? But then why is it visible in vim through a command? I tried [including the syntax file](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#%3asyn-include) but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the coffee.vim you linked to it seems like the dot belongs to the `coffeeDotAccess` syntax item. So you can highlight it just by doing this:

```
:hi coffeeDotAccess ctermfg=blue
```

Comment: You are correct! Stupid mistake on my part xD, thanks a ton. The fact is, the dot highlighting was simply an example for what I'm trying to achieve, and clearly a bad example. How about trying to highlight the `++` operator? Would it not be possible since everything is under a cluster?

Comment: Actually this was indeed the root of my problem haha. Since I had been testing it with the dot operator, it wasn't working, but the way I was suggested to do it is indeed the correct way :) Thanks!

Comment: Actually, for some reason this only works when I do it in vim as a command, but not when I put it in my vimrc, would you happen to have any idea why?

Comment: It's because your vimrc entry is overwritten by the coffee.vim. ``:scriptnames`` should show you the order in which the scripts are loaded. You might want to put your entry into ``~/.vim/after/syntax/coffee.vim``

Comment: Interesting thanks! Actually, another stupid mistake on my part. I actually put that stuff in my color file, `~/.vim/colors/Blaenk.vim`. But you are still right :) `:scriptnames` says my color file is loaded before coffee is. Putting it in an after dir works great :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess a bit at what you need. (I don't speak Coffeescript and your sample regex is way too complicated for me to start reading at the moment).

#### Transparent syntax items

You could have a look at *transparent* syntax rules: (http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_44.html)

```
In a C language file you would like to highlight the () text after a "while"
differently from the () text after a "for".  In both of these there can be
nested () items, which should be highlighted in the same way.  You must make
sure the () highlighting stops at the matching ).  This is one way to do this:

    :syntax region cWhile matchgroup=cWhile start=/while\s*(/ end=/)/
        \ contains=cCondNest
    :syntax region cFor matchgroup=cFor start=/for\s*(/ end=/)/
        \ contains=cCondNest
    :syntax region cCondNest start=/(/ end=/)/ contained transparent
```

#### Partial matches in regex

If you really *just* meant highlighting submatches, have a look at the the

```
\zs      start match
\ze      end match
```

In short,

:match Error /foo\zsbar\zered/

would highlight only 'bar' in 'foobarred'

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, but I'm not sure how to apply this to my situation. Basically, the regex I showed above is one that matches the coffeescript operators, for example, including `++`. Say I want to highlight `++` a different color from the rest, I'm wondering how I could highlight a portion of an existing `syn match` a different color.

Comment: OMG Exactly what I was looking for! `\zs` and `\ze`. Thanks!